# Set table columns equal length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would the css look if I needed to do this. I have a javascript function that gets data and outputs rows. The data matches up (like the first element of row 1 is of the same type as first of row 2, second is same as second etc.)
But sometimes one element of an upper row will be much longer than the corresponding elements, so it doesn't come down like a straight column. How do I fix this?

```
        rowIndex=0;
        while(rowIndex<table.length){
            present_row = $("#table").append("<div class='row'></div>");

            itemIndex= 0;                
            while(itemIndex<table[rowIndex].length){
                present_row.append("<div class='tableItem'>"+ table[rowIndex][itemIndex] +"</div>");
                itemIndex+=1;
            }
            rowIndex+=1
        }
    }
```

What this gives me is a set of rows that aren't

Comment: why are you using divs to display tabular data? you might have to implement a set width tableItem in the css to ensure that they stay in line.

Comment: You should be using a table first of all.  Secondly... without a demo, or the rest of your code, its kind of hard to know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: As @SeanStopnik said, we need to see the beginning and ending of the table. (unless you didn't have one which is a problem in itself)

Answer (score 3):

Use a real table:

```
    rowIndex=0;
    while(rowIndex < table.length) {
        present_row = $("#table").append("<tr></tr>");

        itemIndex= 0;                
        while(itemIndex < table[rowIndex].length) {
            present_row.append("<td class='tableItem'>"+ table[rowIndex][itemIndex] +"</td>");
            itemIndex+=1;
        }
        rowIndex+=1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to make height of rows equal

> $(document).ready(function() {
>       var nHeight = 0;
>       $('.tableItem').each(function() {
>           var defHeight = $(this).height();
>           nHeight = defHeight < nHeight ? nHeight : defHeight;
>       });
>       $('.tableItem').height(nHeight); });
>   });